# Get Value of label control in grid view in User Control by jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Hi I have a user control that contains a grid with label control.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
   <Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Project review date" >
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="reviewDate" ID="lblReviewDate">
      </asp:Label>                
    </ItemTemplate>                
   </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In ASPX page through jquery i want to set the label value.

Comment: Then your first step will be to examine the client-side HTML that you're trying to read.  jQuery has no knowledge of this server-side code, it's only going to see and interact with the resulting client-side HTML.  What does that HTML look like, and what specifically are you trying to read from it?

Answer (score 1):

The controls in a GridView repeat themselves, so their ID will look something like this `GridView2_ctl02_lblReviewDate`

So you can loop all the items in the GridView by class and get/set their values based on the row index.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#<%= GridView2.ClientID %> .reviewDate').each(function (index, element) {
        $(this).text("Value " + index);
    });
</script>
```